# MySQL PASSWORD() function and SpringSecurity ShaPasswordEncoder

Tags: mysql, hash, spring-security

I've got a mysql database that stores passwords using MySQL's PASSWORD() function.  From what I can gather from this URL (and verifying it myself to make sure it applies to my version of MySQL)

> http://www.palominodb.com/blog/2011/12/04/hashing-algorithm-mysql-password

The hashing function for mysql is a double SHA1 hash with the first result converted from binary to hex before hashing it again.

```
SELECT PASSWORD("this_is_a_random_string") as 'pass';

pass: *12E76A751EFA43A177049262A2EE36DA327D8E50

SELECT concat('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1("this_is_a_random_string"))))) as 'pass';

pass: *12E76A751EFA43A177049262A2EE36DA327D8E50
```

So what I'd like to do is use SpringSecurity's ShaPasswordEncoder to allow Spring to work with these hashes.

Other than subclassing my own PasswordEncoder and using ShaPasswordEncoder to build up the processing steps shown in the SQL above, does ShaPasswordEncoder itself have a standard way of setting itself up to work with MySQL's PASSWORD function?

Comment: +1 for interesting revealing) But I agree with Bill Karwin's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

> The PASSWORD() function is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications.